# Verbatim text in forest nodes

Tags: verbatim, forest

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{termtree/.style = {align = center, l sep = 18pt, s sep = 15pt,
  where n children = 0 {tier = leaves}{}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree = {termtree}
[pow [- [6] [3]] [2]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

producing the output

[image]

I would like to replace `pow` by `^` such that I can enter

```
[^ [- [6] [3]] [2]]
```

and the symbol `^` also appears in the graph.

All symbols and numbers should appear in monospace. Wrapping all node contents by `\verb{}` might therefore be ideal. I have not managed, however, to achieve this.

**Edit**

Based on the first three comments below I came up with the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{termtree/.style = {
  align = center,
  font = \ttfamily,
  l sep = 18pt, s sep = 15pt,
  where n children = 0 {tier = leaves}{}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree = {termtree}
[\^{} [- [6] [3]] [2]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

This produces the expected result and leaves only the question if there is any way to replace `\^{}` by `^` inside the `forest` environment.

Comment: I don't use `forest`, but I'm doubtful that `\verb` can be used within it.  (`\verb` is very limited in that it mostly can't be embedded.)  But `\texttt` or `\ttshape` should get the same result except for `^`, which is a special character.  A special character can usually be entered as `\char` followed by <backtick><backslash><character>.

Comment: This seems a bit like an XY problem. Specifying `font=\ttfamily` gets all the text in the mono font. In principle you could make `^` active and give it a different meaning within the tree, but that sounds like more work than is needed.

Comment: Discovering `forest` too: we always learn something new here. :) I second for use of `\texttt{}` instead of `\verb??` With the former I'd try `\textasciicircum` or `\^{}` ;)

Comment: @AlanMunn Making `^` an active character inside the `forest` environment might be overkill. I would be interested, however, on how this could be achieved.

Comment: I see my error has been corrected: it's `\ttfamily` instead of `\ttshape` (which doesn't exist).  Thanks, @AlanMunn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following makes `^` active inside `forest` like suggested by Alan Munn. It uses the `\lowercase` trick to use `~` as the active `^` and LaTeX's `\AddToHook`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{forest}

\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\^
\lowercase{\endgroup
\AddToHook{env/forest/begin}
  {%
    \catcode`\^=13
    \def~{\^{}}%
  }%
}
\forestset{termtree/.style = {
  align = center,
  font = \ttfamily,
  l sep = 18pt, s sep = 15pt,
  where n children = 0 {tier = leaves}{}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree = {termtree}
[^ [- [6] [3]] [2]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

A cleaner way, that exploits `\ttfamily` fonts having `^` at the corresponding slot, instead of using the accent.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{forest}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nx \__matthias_hat: { \char_generate:nn { `\^ } { 12 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\activatehat}{}
  {
   \char_set_active_eq:nN { `\^ } \__matthias_hat:
   \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\forestset{
  termtree/.style = {
    align = center,
    font = \ttfamily,
    l sep = 18pt,
    s sep = 15pt,
    where n children = 0 {tier = leaves}{},
  },
}
\AddToHook{env/forest/begin}{\activatehat}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree = {termtree}
[^ [- [6] [3]] [2]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]